# How to visualize image raw topics of ARdrone 2?

Tags: ros

I am working on navigation of ARdrone 2.0 using ROS and I need to display the video stream from front and bottom camera on the PC's monitor. 
Also, I have installed ARdrone_autonomy package. How can I visualize the ardrone/front/image_raw, ardrone/bottom/image_raw topics?

Thanks in advance,
Samira

Answer (score 1):

Try This: 
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/ardrone/image_raw

Also, you need to investigate in https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy#pre-requirements , in the Cameras Section about the cameras streaming, as well as in the Services Section about how to toggle between cameras.

Hope you find it useful... I'm just learning also!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own display, you can use OpenCV and cv_bridge. Create a node that subscribes to the image topic, and use cv_bridge to get that into a cv::Mat. From there it is very easy to display using cv::imshow().

```
    void callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg) { 
         cv_bridge::CvImagePtr img;
         img = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg,sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_8UC3);
         cv::imshow("my display",img->image);
         cv::waitKey(1);
   }
```